# How to increase min-width in ".MuiSelect-select" in material ui Textfield with Select attribute also how to access Selectfield with Input adornment

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There is a min-width of '16px' in .MuiSelect-select when I observed in chrome dev tools. I am using Material-UI Textfield with Select attribute here. I need to override it to '25px'. Also when I click on Input adornment Select field is not working. I don't understand how to do that.I am providing the codesandbox link with code below. Any help would be really appreciable. Thanks in advance.

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-hjrb6?file=/demo.tsx

screenshot:
[image]

code:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme, fade } from "@material- 
ui/core/styles";
import {TextField, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";
import { TextValidator } from 'react-material-ui-form-validator';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

 const currencies = [
 {
value: 'USD',
label: '$',
 },
 {
  value: 'EUR',
 label: '€',
  },
 {
  value: 'BTC',
 label: '฿',
 },
 {
value: 'JPY',
label: '¥',
},
];

 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
 createStyles({
 root: {
  "& > *": {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "25ch"
  }
  }
 })
 );

  const useStylesReddit = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
 createStyles({


  selectClass: {
  minWidth: '20px'
  }

 })
);

 export const MovingOutRedditTextField = (TextFieldProps) => {
 const classes = useStylesReddit();
  // const iconStyles = makeIconStyles();
  const { id } = TextFieldProps;
   return (
   <TextField
  id={id}
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
    
  }}
  
  InputProps={{
    classes,
    disableUnderline: true,
    endAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="end">
        <Typography
          color="textSecondary"
        >
          currency
        </Typography>
      </InputAdornment>
    )
   }}
  {...TextFieldProps}
   />
  );
 };

 export default function BasicTextFields() {
 const classes = useStyles();
 const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState('EUR');

 const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setCurrency(event.target.value);
 };

  return (


   <MovingOutRedditTextField
  select
  classes={{select:classes.selectClass}}
  required
  style={{width:'400px'}}
  label="Return"
  id="securityDepoistReturn"
  value={currency}
  
  variant="filled"
>
  {currencies.map((option) => (
        <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
  </MovingOutRedditTextField>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

target the `select` class using `classes` prop of select.

```
<Select
  classes={{select:classes.selectClass}}
>
  <MenuItem value="">
    <em>None</em>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({    selectClass:{
      minWidth:'25px'
    }
  }),
);
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

#### Update

As per recent comment, `TextBox` is used and `select` prop is passed to make it a selectbox. so in this case to manipulate the `min-width` of the select, pass the classes object in the `SelectProps` prop of the `TextBox`. Props in  `SelectProps` applied to the `Select` element.

```
<TextField
  SelectProps={{
      classes:{
        select:classes.selectClass
      },
   }}
{...other props}
/>
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks mate. The thing is actually I am using Textfield and used 'Select' attribute for Select field. I've applied the changes that you mentioned above but its not working. I've provided the codesandbox link. Can you please look into it. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-hjrb6?file=/demo.tsx Also when I am clicking the "currency" inside the Selectfield, the Selectfield not showing the options. I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you try this one mate.https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-bykj0?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: please update your question accordingly.. Code snippet and codesandbox link

Comment: I have updated my question according to my requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Rajiv for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227727/discussion-between-gowtham-manthena-and-rajiv).

Answer (score 0):

```
   const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    select: {
      minWidth: "200px !important",
      width: 2
    }
  }),
);


<Select
      labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
      id="demo-controlled-open-select"
      className={classes.select}
 >
```

`!important` let you overwrite the default value but try to avoid its over-use

And in select component just call this in className, `min-width` is used for responsiveness you still need to give its width but if u define min-width then it won't get smaller than the defined min-width.